# Import/Export Plugin Settings for Wordpress

Tags: import, wordpress, export

How do I import/export the settings for multiple Wordpress plugins from one site to another? Preferably throught the Wordpress UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not.
Each plugin have your own type of configurations and only with a export and import of a mysql database can pass your settings to another site.

After export and import run this query:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://__www.old-site.com__', 'http://__www.new-site.com__') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://__www.old-site.com__','http://__www.new-site.com__');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://__www.old-site.com__', 'http://__www.new-site.com__');
```

Answer (score 2):

WP Options Importer  plugin looks like it does just that.

[wordpress plugin link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/options-importer/)

Comment: You better explain a bit then provide a reference link

Comment: It may no longer be maintained or supported and may have compatibility issues when used with more recent versions of WordPress.